C# WPF - How to bind size of XAML element to int in ViewModel?
I am trying to understand how bindings work, and have made this small example to better understand.
I have made a simple border in the MainWindow, and am trying to bind the height/width of the border to values in the ViewModel, as shown:
MainWindow.xaml
    <StackPanel Margin="0 30 0 0">
        <Border Background="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Width="{Binding WidthOfBorder}"
                Height="{Binding HeightOfBorder}">
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

MainWindowViewModel.cs
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public int WidthOfBorder;
        public int HeightOfBorder;

        public MainWindowViewModel() 
        {
            WidthOfBorder = 200;
            HeightOfBorder = 100;
        }
    }

How i intend the MainWindow to look like when i do this:

However, it does not work. It appears i don't fully understand how to do binding. Can someone help me?

try and add Mode=TwoWay to your bindings

Data binding only works with properties, not fields. E.g. public int WidthOfBorder { get; }. Also note that Width and Height are double values, so you may want to bind them to view model properties of type double .
